# Error when getting data from JSON Nested loop in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I tried this but getting error in for loop optJSONObject(i)

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "success"
    },
    "data": {
        "updates": [
                    {
                        "id":"67",                  
                        "date":"6 months ago",
                        "update_type": "7",
                        "update_id": "67",
                        "name":"ravi"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"68",                  
                        "date":"3 months ago",
                        "update_type": "5",
                        "update_id": "68",
                        "name":"paresh"
                    },

                    {
                        "id":"69",                  
                        "date":"1 months ago",
                        "update_type": "6",
                        "update_id": "69",
                        "name":"sampath"
                    },

                    {
                        "id":"62",                  
                        "date":"9 months ago",
                        "update_type": "6",
                        "update_id": "62",
                        "name":"raju"
                             }
        ]
    }
}
```

The code i tried for this is :

```
try {
    InputStream is = null;

    is =  getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);


    //CONVERTS STREAM OBJ IN STRING OBJ
    mJSONString             =   convertStreamToString(is);
    JSONObject obj          =   new JSONObject(mJSONString);
    JSONObject dataobj      =   obj.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONObject updateobj    =   dataobj.getJSONObject("update");

    //System.out.println(new JSONObject(update)toString(2));
    for(int i=0; i<updateobj.length(); i++){

        JSONObject object       =   updateobj.optJSONObject(i);
        mUpdates                =   new Mobile_UpdateActivity();

        mUpdates.update_id      =   object.getString("update_id");
        mUpdates.site_id        =   object.getString("site_id");
        mUpdates.update_type    =   object.getString("update_type");

        System.out.println(mUpdates.update_id);
        System.out.println(mUpdates.site_id);
        System.out.println(mUpdates.update_type);
    }
```

}

But I'm facing an error at **optJSONObject(i)

> Error: The method optJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not
>   applicable for the arguments (int)**

Comment: i tried like this...
but getting error in for loop optJSONObject(i).
plz respond to this issue.

try {
InputStream is = null;
is =  getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myfile);       //CONVERTS STREAM OBJ IN STRING OBJ    
mJSONString = convertStreamToString(is);
JSONObject obj  =  new JSONObject(mJSONString);
JSONObject dataobj = obj.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject updateobj = dataobj.getJSONObject("update");

Comment: for(int i=0; i<updateobj.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject object  = updateobj.optJSONObject(i); 
mUpdates    =  new Mobile_UpdateActivity();
mUpdates.update_id  = object.getString("id");
mUpdates.site_id  = object.getString("name");
mUpdates.update_type         =       object.getString("date");
System.out.println(mUpdates.id);
System.out.println(mUpdates.name);
System.out.println(mUpdates.date);
}

Answer (score 0):

you are getting following warning  :

> optJSONObject(i) Error : The method optJSONObject(String) in the type
>   JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)

because in current json String `updates` is an `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` but you are trying to convert an JSONArray to JSONObject.you are calling `JsonObject.optJSONObject` for an JsonObject which require an String as parameter instead of  `JSONArray.optJSONObject` which require an index of item in current JsonArray. change your code as to avoid current warning :

```
    //...your code here...
    JSONObject obj          =   new JSONObject(mJSONString);
    JSONObject dataobj      =   obj.getJSONObject("data");

    // get update jsonArray from dataobj JSONObject 
    JSONArray updateobj    =   dataobj.getJSONArray("update");
    //...your code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing line :

```
JSONObject updateobj    =   dataobj.getJSONObject("update");
```

to

```
JSONArray updateobj    =   dataobj.getJSONArray("update");
```

and then in for loop :

```
JSONObject object       =   updateobj.optJSONObject(i);
```

to

```
JSONObject object       =   updateobj.get(i);
```

Comment: JSONObject getJSONObject(java.lang.String key) 
          Get the JSONObject value associated with a key.